# How to create a variable, specific to an environment?

Tags: environments

I am writing a publication and, in there, I need to reference problems and solutions. A problem looks like this:

```
\documentclass[graybox]{svmult} % Springer template for monographs

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry} % Type of page
\usepackage{anysize} % Size of margins
\usepackage{type1cm}
\usepackage{makeidx}         % allows index generation
\usepackage{graphicx}        % standard LaTeX graphics tool
\usepackage{multicol}         % used for the two-column index
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc} % places footnotes at page bottom
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}       % selects Times Roman as basic font
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}

%%% A problem
\begin{problem}
\label{prob1}
Solve in $t$: $\int_0^t x e^{-x} dx$.
\end{problem}

%%% A solution to that problem
\begin{sol}{prob1}
The integral function can be solved by approximating its values...
\end{sol}

\end{document}
```

This works and notice how a solution is referencing a problem.

#### Problem

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
\begin{problem}{Values of an integral function}
\label{prob1}
Solve in $t$: $\int_0^t x e^{-x} dx$.
\end{problem}

\begin{sol}{???}
The integral function can be solved by approximating its values...
\end{sol}
```

Basically I want to:

1. Define a text in the problem (not to be shown).
2. Reference that text in the solution and show it.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Rather than posting code fragments it is better to give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Currently we have to guess what packages etc you are using and this makes it really hard to help you. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: I am fixing it, sorry

Comment: Could you please clarify exactly what you want to achieve (but cannot currently achieve)? In particular, what do you mean by 'reference that text' in (2), given that the 'text' isn't shown as part of (1)? It will probably help if you show your current definitions of the `prob` and `sol` environments.